# How to query USB serial device, capture output and exit?

Tags: bash, shell-script, usb, tty, serial-port

I have several Arduino devices, connected to linux box. The only difference between them is what they answer on connect. They are not distinguisheable by `lsusb` command. Although I don't know how to convert output of `lsusb` to `ttyUSB?` name, I was unable to find my device anyway:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
...
```

But if I connect to a device by `cu`, I can distinguish them:

```
$ cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 9600
Connected.
OK
~.
Disconnected.
$ cu -l /dev/ttyUSB1 -s 9600
Connected.

Relay module awaiting commands
Command 'help' is for help
~.
Disconnected.
```

Can I grab such output by `cu` or by any other means with bash script being able to determine a device?

---

Can't distinguish Arduinos by serial too

```
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep '{serial}'
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"

# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB1 | grep '{serial}'
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
```

Comment: What does `cu` do on EOF on the input? I.e. hitting Ctrl-D if you run it interactively. If it exits on that, something like `true | cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 9600` might do, it'd connect an empty output from `true` to `cu`. Though of course it might still exit before reading any input, so maybe `sleep .1 | cu ...`

Comment: It ignores `Ctrl-D`, but it exits on `~.`

Comment: well, yes, stupid me, maybe `(sleep .1; printf '~.\n') | cu ...` then? Unless `cu` has some options itself that would be more to the point...

Answer (score 1):

I did this way:

```
devices="/dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/ttyUSB1"

for device in $devices
do

   if timeout 10s cat $device | grep -q OK
   then
     ...
```